JavaFX code works in package 'application' but not in other packages
first of all i work with eclipse 2024-03 and the most recent javafx SDK.
I have some javaFX code that works when it is located in the application package that is created automatically when creating a new javafx project. But when i create a new package in the same project and try to run the same code i get the following error:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx. not found
Can someone tell me what settings i need to change for that specific package?
Edit: after trying again i get these errors:
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1085)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class zwischenuebungen.LayoutContainer
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:883)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class zwischenuebungen.LayoutContainer (in module Test1) because module Test1 does not export zwischenuebungen to module javafx.graphics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:489)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:795)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more


Since this question will likely be around for a long time and given that every few months there is a new JavaFX SDK released, saying: the most recent javafx SDK is ambiguous. I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the exact [JavaFX] version that you are using. Having said that, from the stack trace in your question, it looks like you need to add exports zwischenuebungen; to your module-info.java file.

IMO: Just get rid of a modular application and create a non modular one - everything will work just fine. Just in case: You fond a non modular template app example here: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

Option: Modular
This issue has to do with your module-info.java.
Probably it has a line exports <somepackagename>, where <somepackagename> is not zwischenuebungen, which is the package you are trying to use.
You either need to export or open the package for your application.
The error message tells you what package you need to open and what module you need to open the package to:
module Test1 does not export zwischenuebungen to module javafx.graphics

So a minimal module-info.java (you may need more statements for your actual application), is:
module Test1 {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports zwischenuebungen;
}

That gives complete visibility of the zwischenuebungen package to other modules.
Or to just open to javafx.graphics:
module Test1 {
    requires javafx.controls;
    opens zwischenuebungen to javafx.graphics;
}

Which restricts visibility to the named module.
The reason this is required is that the javafx.graphics module is using reflection to instantiate and launch your JavaFX application, and that requires the package containing the application to be open the javafx.graphics module to work.
This is mentioned in the Application javadoc:

Deploying an Application as a Module
If the Application subclass is in a named module then that class must
be accessible to the javafx.graphics module. Otherwise, an exception
will be thrown when the application is launched. This means that in
addition to the class itself being declared public, the module must
export (or open) the containing package to at least the
javafx.graphics module.
For example, if com.foo.MyApplication is in the foo.app module, the
module-info.java might look like this:
module foo.app {
    exports com.foo to javafx.graphics;
}


Option: Non-modular
Your other option, as mentioned in the comments, is to make your application non-modular.
Instructions on doing that are at openjfx.io (I won't reiterate or comment on them here).
Suppose it is a complex application with lots of third-party dependencies. In that case, the non-modular structure may be the way to go.  But for a simple application with minimal dependencies just on the JRE and JavaFX, it is probably best as a module (IMO) as that gives you more straight-forward and easy-to-use packaging options.
Reference

Understanding Java modules.
What's the difference between --add-exports and --add-opens in Java 9?

